# while loop with request http python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, while-loop, request

Good morning. I created this function to send a notification and turn on a led but while the http page loads, the script blocks until it has finished loading the page. What can I enter in order to have the page load while the script continues?

```
def alm_dir():
   print("HELP")
   res = requests.get('http://192.168.1.171/LED=ON')
```

Comment: You may need asyncio as your solution, please look at the following link https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

Comment: Question is a bit confusing, as your code doesn't have any while loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into threading, this allows the script to start a function on the side and then continue running while the second function runs in the background

https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/